# Visual Studio 2012 indirect reference not copying dlls to bin

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, dll-reference

I am using Visual Studio 2012. The projects in question are in VB.Net.

I have a Web Project (MVC3) which references another project we'll call it the webLogic.dll it's basically the go between from the web site to the database. The webLogic.dll has a reference to our dataStorage.dll (this has the SQL and database connection details and such) so the Web Project does not have a reference to the dataStorage.dll. The intent, not that it is completely relevant, was to set it up so the web site doesn't know or care how the data is stored.

Here is the issue, If I run a clean and then rebuild on the solution, the dataStorage.dll does not get copied to the Web Project's bin directory but the webLogic.dll does get copied. Obviously when debugging this fails miserably.

However, if I then run a rebuild on the solution (without doing a clean first) the dataStorage.dll does get copied to the Web Project's bin folder.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this happens or what I can do to make sure the dataStorage.dll is copied over without adding a reference to it?